# What is it that you're doing when you do a single t test on one predictor of a multiple regression model?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics, t-test

I hope my interpretation is correct. When you're doing a t-test on a single predictor of a multiple regression model, are you looking at how it behaves while the other coefficients are fixed?

Comment: You need to appreciate difference between t-test and  computation of t-statistic.

Comment: yes, it's exacly the meaning! the observed t is calculated with standart error that includes the other predicters (tolarence and IVF- 1/1-r12).